# How to remove the double registered item in task bar notifications

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

[image]

I found that I have my Cygwin xwin is double registered in task bar notifictions. How can I delete one of them?

Comment: Is it running as a process in the background?  If so, just kill the process with the task manager.

Comment: I found this: http://www.askvg.com/how-to-remove-unwanted-items-from-hide-inactive-icons-customization-box-in-windows-xp-vista-and-7/

Comment: @William Jackson : I tried, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @prosseek I tried those instructions, too, and they didn't work for me, either. However, I found that they do work if you delete the registry values while explorer.exe is not running. I'll post an answer ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Right-click on the taskbar and select **Start Task Manager**.
2. In the **Processes** tab of **Windows Task Manager**, select **explorer.exe** and click the **End Process** button.
   [image: Windows Task Manager]
3. From the **File** menu of **Windows Task Manager**, select **New Task (Run...)** and run `regedit`.
   [image: Create New Task]
4. In **Registry Editor**, browse to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Class\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify` and delete the entries for `IconStreams` and `PastIconsStream`
5. From the **File** menu of **Windows Task Manager**, select **New Task (Run...)** and run `explorer`.